# HTML Page isn't working

Tags: html

I am new to HTML and coding so sorry. My code shows a link to a website on my page, but it isn't working. See below:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>My navigation</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <a href=" www.google.com">this google!</a>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Doesn't work 'eh?  It doesn't matter if you're new to coding or not.  You should learn to ask a proper question.  What exactly do you mean by "doesn't work"?  There are so many things it could be... we can't assume what you know or don't know at this stage.

Comment: Also just for future reference, you should refer to the [ask] guide. This should help you with asking questions.

Comment: Define 'not working'. I'm assuming you're attempting to go to `www.google.com`? You used a **relative** URL in your link, so it will take you to `www.yoursite.com/www.google.com`. Affix `http://` to link to an external site ;)

Comment: Please go on "my computer > organize > Folder and Search Option > click on view tab > unchecked hide extensions for known file types"  then click on ok button. After that please check your html file extensions ".html"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<a>` tag is incorrectly formatted. In order to link to a website, make sure you format it as follows: `<a href="http://www.[...]">`.

See your updated code below:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>My navigation</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <a href="http://www.google.com/">this is google!</a>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Let me know if you need any other help.

Comment: Funnily enough, making this a code snippet doesn't demonstrate that this is the correct way to fix it. You can't navigate to `http` links in stack snippets, and I don't think google will allow its content to be embedded in an `<iframe>` anyway.

Comment: You can middle-mouse click on Stack snippets to get to external sites; the link has indeed been corrected :)

Comment: @PatrickRoberts true, but at least the snippets are nicely formatted. An you can always open the link in a new tab.

Comment: Just add `target="_blank"` and that wouldn't be necessary.

Comment: That would work. But maybe the OP doesn't want the link to open in a new tab. If OP had specified the link was to open in a new tab that would be fine. But to stick with their original code, it's just a standard `<a>`. The snippet displays the right code and if OP were to replace their code with the one provided, it would work.